# Clear memory for Objects / Arrays allocated for a file in ExpressJS ( Node JS) server

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, pm2

I am working on a feature using Express JS and inside the server folder I created a feature.js file. Inside the feature.js file I am creating objects, arrays like :

```
let instances = {}
instances[uid] = some_operations;
//.... some other operations;
```

so that I can idetify an application coming from browser using an `uid`.
Now, I want to delete an instance object by refering an uid like

```
delete instances['fe890abju-jai900dd-i18718iol'];
```

Is that possible to delete object ( instances[uid] ) inside that feature.js file without stopping the server ? Or Does restarting pm2 clear the memory of the node processes running till that time and is that suggestable ? Or is there any possible way to do that operation without stopping the server ?